# Port forwarding from wired, wireless to android phone

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a TP-Link TD-8816 (wired - modem router) connected to a Netgear wireless router. I have my Android app listening on a port, say 10001.

I have been following the manual for TP-Link to port forward, assuming I need to do this to access the port on my phone, but I can't seem to get to my Android port from the Internet. From inside my LAN however I can access my phone from a PC where both my PC and phone are connected to the Netgear wireless.

The Tp-Link is between the Internet and my Netgear wireless. Is it even possible to access my phone port from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

Check you have set the appropriate NAT rules (port forwarding) and that you have your phone configured to use your NAT router IP address as its gateway on the WiFi interface.

You should also ensure that your phone's firewall is not blocking this port. You can try turning it off just to test and then open the desired ports.

Comment: The problem was finding out my wireless router's ip address(external ip) with respect to my modem. Now the NAT rule works.I can't upvote yet.